# Having regex in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

The bash script does many things. However, at beginning it should start if the input passed to the script is a directory path. For example, 
right way of telling directory path is "/var/lib/test", and 
incorrect way is "/var/%%^?/test".

where test is a directory and not a file.

The directory path can contain characters. [A-Za-z0-9/_-]

My script is as below -

```
#!/bin/bash
dirPath="/var/lib/test"
if [[ ! ${dirPath} =~ "^/[A-Za-z0-9/_-]+$" ]]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Here, dirPath can have any path provided from another script.

please let me know the error here.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question. So the above script returns `Success`. Is that expected? Can you give some examples of when it should return `Failure` and `Success`?

Comment: Is the issue the characters in the path? `/var/%%^?/test` is a valid pathname on Unix. Would it be enough to test whether the given path denotes an existing directory?

Comment: The script should test if the given directory path is valid or not.
Valid directory path includes characters - [A-Za-z0-9_-/]

Comment: That doesn't exactly answer my or @Kusalananda's questions. Please read them again and try to answer more precisely. Give some examples of failing and working strings, and explain if you only will accept a subset of correct paths.

Comment: I still think Success and Failure (or the !) is not what you want.

Comment: @Goro The `9` is the end of the range of digits, `0-9`. The slash and underscore are just a slash and an underscore.

Comment: Given that the question title mentions regexes, and the code snippet uses the `[[ =~ ]]` test, It seems reasonable to assume that the meaning of the question is about testing a variable against a regex. A discussion on what constitutes or should constitute a valid filename _in the context of the questioners program_ seems beside the point. Now, the question isn't the clearest English I've seen, but I don't think we can assume native-level English from all questions?

Comment: @Goro Inside `[...]` in a regular expression, there are no delimiters.  Even backslashes would be taken as literal backslashes.

Comment: @ Kusalananda. Correct!

Comment: @Goro, Bash's `=~` doesn't take slashes to delimit the regex

Comment: @Kusalananda, depends. `perl -ne 'print if /[0-9/]/'` gives an error for the regex. OTOH, `sed -ne '/[0-9/]/p'` works on GNU (at least).

Comment: @ilkkachu Right you are. PCRE is not my native language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [[ ! ${dirPath} =~ "^/[A-Za-z0-9/_-]+$" ]]; then
    echo "Success"
```

This will test `$dirPath` against the literal string `^/[A-Za-z0-9/_-]+$`, and invert the result. In other words, it will print `Success` when `$dirPath` is anything other than that literal string. This is because quoted characters in a regex lose their special meaning in current versions of Bash, and of course the `!` works to invert the test.

If you want to test that variable against the actual regex, it's easiest to put the regex in a variable first, and leave it unquoted (using a variable may not be strictly necessary, but avoids some parsing issues with complex regexes):

```
dirPath="/var/lib/test"
re='^/[A-Za-z0-9/_-]+$'
if [[ ${dirPath} =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "'$dirPath' starts with a slash, and is composed of alphanumerics, hyphens, underscores and slashes only"
else
    echo "'$dirPath' is of a forbidden format"
fi
```

Of course, if you want to test if that path is an existing directory, then you'd use `-d`:

```
if [[ -d $dirPath ]]; then
    echo "'$dirPath' exists and is a directory
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes from the regex:

```
[[ ! "${dirPath}" =~ ^/[A-Za-z0-9/_-]+$ ]]
```

Quoting the regex forces string matching since [Bash 3.2](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS).

Compare [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes).

> Note: while this fixes your script, it does not properly check if the path is a correct directory path. Refer to @Kusalanandas answer how to do a proper check.

Answer (score 2):

This answer focuses on the first part of the question which (currently) reads:

> However, at beginning it should start if the input passed to the script is a directory path.

The rest of the question is an attempt at doing this by matching a particular regular expression against a pathname to try to figure out whether it's a valid directory pathname.

A script should not generally impose an arbitrary naming scheme on the user's directories or files without reason.  The pathname `/var/%%^?/test` is perfectly valid on a system where there exists a directory called `%%^?` under `/var` and where this directory contains a subdirectory called `test`.

What your script is *really* concerned about is whether it's given a pathname to an *existing directory*.  Whatever the directory path is is less important.

This may be done with

```
#!/bin/bash

dirPath=$1

if [ ! -d "$dirPath" ]; then
    printf '"%s" is not a valid directory path\n' "$dirPath" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

After this `if`-statement, you know that `"$dirPath"` is the path to an existing directory.  The pathname to the directory is (in the above code) taken from the first command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

to check if its file or dir you don't need regex - use:

```
if [ -d "${testpath}" ] ; then
    echo "$testpath is a directory";
```